# How to use paperclip to upload files other than images ...like pdf,docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload resume in my applyforjobs.Its working fine,i mean i can get browse button to upload files.But when i show the view page its not showing the pdf file that i upload,instead its showing just the name of the file. I also checked that folder which gets generated by default and that folder contains the pdfs which i uploaded during create aaction,which means upload thing is working fine.but i am not able to show that pdf.

---

Following is the code in my applyforjob.rb model for paperclip attachment :

```
has_attached_file :resume,:styles => { :small => "150x150>" }
```

Following is the code of applyforjobs/form.html.haml for uploading file :

```
= f.label :resume, "Upload resume".html_safe
= f.file_field :resume
```

Following is the code of applyforjobs/show.html.haml for showing file :

```
= image_tag @appliedusers.resume.url(:small)
```

but its not showing that pdf file.What am i supposed to write to upload and show files like pdf or docs?

Answer (score 2):

Since `paperclip` is a general purpose attachment uploading gem, as stated in it's Readme, it natively supports uploading files of any kind.

I suggest that you:

1. remove `:styles => { :small => "150x150>" }` parameter from the `has_attached_file`
2. **write a paperclip callback which will generate a thumbnail image from pdf file**
3. define a method in model, say `resume_thumbnail`, which will be returning a path to generated file
4. call the following in your view

   ```
   = image_tag @appliedusers.resume_thumbnail
   ```

No wonder `image_tag @appliedusers.resume.url(:small)` doesn't work for you: `paperclip` knows nothing about PDFs. `paperclip` blindly sees PDF file as a common *file*, and thus unable to do any kind of processing applicable to images only.

Answer (score 0):

@ , After saving the pdf you need to create a image which convert pdf to image to show on browser
 I did this like -

**self.save              ##save pdf in paperclip

create_preview_image     ##call this method

def create_preview_image

```
file_name = File.join(Rails.root, 'public',   self.document.url.split('?')[0]) if self.document

return unless file_name.present?

pdf = Magick::ImageList.new(file_name) 

return unless pdf.present?

png_file = Tempfile.new(["#{rand(9999).to_s}",'.png'])

pdf[0].write(png_file.path) do

    self.quality = 100

end

self.preview = png_file

self.save
```

end**